# CSS issue - footer goes too long?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm having a bit of a problem with the footer on this site. I am looking for it to have a set minimum height and flow to the bottom of the page no matter the resolution. Kind of like a sticky footer but I want it to butt up against the end of the container div above it.

The issue is consistent across all modern browsers (Safari, Chrome, IE, and Firefox).

Too much CSS to post here but Firebug or a view source will show the corresponding styling. Any help would greatly appreciated.

http://034732e.netsolhost.com/gdlsk_joomla/

Comment: Can you be more specific? I see a light gray footer with some content in it. The light gray flows to the bottom of the page? What do you want where? The text at the bottom of the light gray are? The light gray area not to be so big? A screenshot would help a lot =).

Comment: The footer size is the issue. It's 693px high on any browser. I just want the footer to fill to the bottom of the browser window no matter how big.

Comment: http://imgur.com/XOC6c - That's a shot of the page with the height set to 150px only. I'd like the footer to extend the rest of the page to the bottom on larger browsers. Don't know why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the screenshot. Your description makes more sense now. I would do the following. Right now you have something like

```
<body>
  <page>
     <header />
     <bodycontent />
  </page>
  <footer />
<body>
```

I would consider something like this

```
<body height: 100%;>
    <page height: 100%; background: gray;>
      <header background: black; />
      <bodycontent background: black; />
      <footer />
    </page>
<body>
```

Basically what we do is set body and page to 100% which means they take up the entire screen. Page uses the same bg color as the footer. Finally we set header and bodycontent to have black backgrounds so that they cover up the Page's gray.

Comment: I like your thinking. I was thinking about using backgrounds to workaround the issue too. The problem is that there are transparent pngs on that page as well as a striped background that needs to be shown.

Comment: You will need to double wrap it then. Or use javascript. CSS isn't smart enough to do what you want as is. So place `page` inside another wrapper, this one having the gray background and then apply your styled backgrounds to page. If you need the entire body to feature a styled background then I think you are out of luck on the CSS side.

Comment: The super hack award goes to Mr. T. Sherman! Thanks for the tip. Not the ideal solution I was looking for but it works. Across all browsers I've tested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying 100% height on the footer is not doing what you think it does. You're telling it that you want the height to be 100% of the body, it doesn't just "expand to fill" the remaining space. It will actually be 100% height, plus everything else you've added in. It is achieving your minimum height of 150px and more.

Comment: I tried setting it to auto but it doesn't flow to bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

try this changes in you css:

```
body > #page {
height: 100%;
}

@#footer: remove-> property top:0;
add-> property bottom:0;
```

Comment: I tried setting it to auto but it doesn't flow to bottom of the screen. Can anyone else confirm this on a large resolution monitor.

Comment: i have edited my answer with some changes please try this one also.

Comment: @#footer: remove-> property top:0;
add-> property bottom:0;

This code is messing up the rest of my css. Does it need to be formatted a certain way? Perhaps in brackets?

Comment: i think the way i wrote it's confusing you, it's not like that i have just mentioned to remove the top position and add bottom position at the #footer in your css,

Comment: Oh I got you. Tried that before. Doesn't work though. Using the combination of the two wrappers, I was able to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, it should look like this:

HTML

```
<footer id="wrapper" class="main_footer">
    <nav>
      <a href="#">A</a>
      <a href="#">B</a>
      <a href="#">C</a>
   </nav>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 }
```